# Switching audio with buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, audio

i have some MP3 audio in my files and i would like to play them in WPF using buttons , for example theres three button : previous , start , next . When i click start button first audio is being played , when i click next , the next audio is being played when i click previous , it goes to the previous audio and play it ... i tried :

```
   string[] fileNames;
    int iCurrentImageCount;
    int iMaxImageCount;

       private void SwipeLeftProcess()
    {
        if (iCurrentImageCount > 0)
            iCurrentImageCount--;
        else
            iCurrentImageCount = iMaxImageCount - 1;


        PlayAudio();
    }

    private void SwipeRightProcess()
    {
        if (iCurrentImageCount < iMaxImageCount - 1)
            iCurrentImageCount++;
        else
            iCurrentImageCount = 0;


        PlayAudio();
    }
     private void PlayAudio()
    {
        MediaPlayer ap = new MediaPlayer();        
        ap.Open(new Uri("/StoryAudio/" + fileNames[iCurrentImageCount], UriKind.Relative)); /ERROR here
        ap.Play();
    }
  private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Start
    {
       PlayAudio();}
```

Am i doing this correct? i can do this when i am doing for Images but not audio , theres an error with ap.Open , stating that it is null.

Comment: What is the error? Are you sure that the Uri you create points to the file? Is the StoryAudio directory a sub directory of the directory where the executable is located?

Comment: yes is a sub directory of the executable

Comment: You noted the ap.Open line has an "ERROR" what error is it? Did you check with File.Exists whether the files exist?

Comment: Ok there is like 10 mp3 files in that folder and i want to play them . When i do using image , i can just Image.Source = folder , but how do i do this if i want to play audio?

Comment: i solved the null error on open line

Comment: In XAML you can use the MediaElement but you need to switch the files manually. It should provided a completed event that you can use to play the next one. For the solution for your issue, share it please